# How to delete a locked folder

Tags: locking, directory

I tried lot of things to delete a locked folder but I was not able to do it. I tried Process Explorer too. But nuthing works? Is there any other way we can delete the locked folder? I also saw various links on the stackoverflow too. That is also not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to do this programmatically? Or are you just looking for a tool to "unlock" files?

If you are looking for a freeware tool - [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) has worked really well for me when something gets screwed up and files/folders can't be deleted/moved.

Comment: I am looking for some tool basically.